Kernel Mode Driver linking assembly
recently I started using another code editor to write drivers, I decided to use MSBuild which worked perfectly, I just had to set up a vcxproj file and so. I was thinking about writing assembly and assembling it using ML.exe, the issue is that MSBuild outputs the finished .sys file. I'm not sure how to link asmtest.obj and driver.sys together
I've tried researching something about this topic unfortunately didnt find anything and I failed.

in what problem use asm ? how is obj generated after compile c/c++ linked into final binary ?! simply add obj to linker input. and why not use vs

@RbMm how do I do that in VS?

add file to solution. setup custom build for it

@RbMm I figured it out, I have another issue, when Im trying to call KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel it says thate its an unresolved external symbol but I am linking ntoskrnl.lib towards it

despite ntoskrnl.exe export KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel (in x64, but not in x86 - here hal.dll export it) in lib files no such symbol and header files must redirect KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel  to KfRaiseIrql

@RbMm so what do I do?

need deep understand how compiler and linker work. until no - nothing todo

Oh man, why not just explain

but how is this explain ? why not think yourself ? how you declare KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel ? where it declare ? search in headers. x86 or x64 ? look in lib files.. etc. need know all this before go to kernel

I found its exported in hal.lib

this is mean you use x86

@RbMm I tried to link it and put hal.lib inside additional dependecies in vcxproj file yet its still unresolved external symbol
